# Markdown to HTML Table Borders with CSS

Tags: css, latex, markdown, pandoc

I've got the following markdown table that is the contents of my *'input.md'* markdown file.

```
Col01 | Col02
----- | -----
DataX | DataY
```

I pasted the CSS shown far below into notepad and saved it as *'custom.css'*. I put this *'custom.css'* in the same directory as my input.md file and ran the following command.

```
pandoc -t html --css=custom.css -o output.html input.md
```

The expected output is a table with lines showing as borders. The actual output is a table without borders, although it is nicely aligned like a table should be. What did I do wrong?

*Here's my custom CSS:*

```
table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
table th {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
table td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
}


/* Add border for the last row of the table.           */
/*      (Might be of use for table footnotes, later).  */
/* tr:last-child td { border-top: 2px solid black; }   */
```

Comment: Did you check the rendered HTML and confirm that your CSS is actually referenced (a `link` tag to the file exists in the `head`)? Did you check that your browser is actually loading the CSS file? Have you used your browser's dev tools to "inspect" the table and see which CSS rules are actually being applied to it?

Comment: Can't you add your own css (below the link to the custom css file) that sets the table cell's borders?

Comment: I need to do some research on the questions you asked. I don't even understand what you're asking. Thanks for the guidance and I'll look into these things.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is not included in the output unless pandoc is called with the `-s` or `--standalone` option. Adding that option should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `pandoc -t html` is it generates HTML document without the header. Just take HTML file it generates and add this at the beginning:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
...here comes your CSS file content...
</style>
</head>
<body>
...rest of the HTML file generated by pandoc...
</body>
</html>
```

and also append these two lines mentioned above at the end (so we play nice :-)).